# bash script - store multiple outputs of a command in separate variables

Tags: bash

I'd like to store the ouput of the following command in separate variables for each IP adress:

```
ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: You could trivially store those values in a Bash array. The man page has details on working with arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement to store the values as separate variables seems out of place. Just produce the list, and loop over it or whatever.

Tangentially, you really want to lose the long chain of `grep`s.

```sh
ifconfig |
awk '$1 == "inet" && ($2 != "127.0.0.1" && $2 != "addr:") { print $2 }
$1 == "inet" && $2 == "addr:" && $3 != "127.0.0.1" { print $3 }'
```

To assign the result to a Bash array, try

```sh
array=($(ifconfig | awk '...'))
```

but more often than not, you probably just want to loop over the result:

```sh
ifconfig |
awk '...' |
while IFS='' read -r ip; do
    # something with "$ip"
done
```

Comment: `readarray -t array < <(ifconfig | awk '...')`, unless you're stubbornly supporting the system `bash` on macOS :)